# Difference between statsmodel OLS and scikit linear regression

Tags: regression, python, scikit-learn, statsmodels

I have a question about two different methods from different libraries which seems doing same job. I am trying to make linear regression model.

Here is the code which I using statsmodel library with OLS :

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1)

x_train = sm.add_constant(X_train)
model = sm.OLS(y_train, x_train)
results = model.fit()

print "GFT + Wiki / GT  R-squared", results.rsquared
```

This print out **GFT + Wiki / GT  R-squared 0.981434611923**

and the second one is scikit learn library Linear model method:

```
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

predictions = model.predict(X_test)

print 'GFT + Wiki / GT R-squared: %.4f' % model.score(X_test, y_test)
```

This print out **GFT + Wiki / GT R-squared: 0.8543**

So my question is the both method prints our R^2 result but one is print out 0.98 and the other one is 0.85.

From my understanding, OLS works with training dataset. So my questions,

- Is there a way that work with test data set with OLS ?
- Is the traning data set score gives us any meaning(In OLS we didn't use test data set)? From my past knowledge we have to work with test data.
- What is the difference between OLS and scikit linear regression. Which one we use for calculating the score of the model ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First in terms of usage. You can get the prediction in statsmodels in a very similar way as in scikit-learn, except that we use the results instance returned by `fit`

`predictions = results.predict(X_test)`

Given the predictions, we can calculate statistics that are based on the prediction error

`prediction_error = y_test - predictions`

There is a separate list of functions to calculate goodness of prediction statistics with it, but it's not integrated into the models, nor does it include R squared. (I've never heard of R squared used for out of sample data.) Calculating those requires a bit more work by the user and statsmodels does not have the same set of statistics, especially not for classification or models with a binary response variable.

To your other two points:

Linear regression is in its basic form the same in statsmodels and in scikit-learn. However, the implementation differs which might produce different results in edge cases, and scikit learn has in general more support for larger models. For example, statsmodels currently uses sparse matrices in very few parts.

The most important difference is in the surrounding infrastructure and the use cases that are directly supported.

Statsmodels follows largely the traditional model where we want to know how well a given model fits the data, and what variables "explain" or affect the outcome, or what the size of the effect is.
Scikit-learn follows the machine learning tradition where the main supported task is chosing the "best" model for prediction.

As a consequence, the emphasis in the supporting features of statsmodels is in analysing the training data which includes hypothesis tests and goodness-of-fit measures, while the emphasis in the supporting infrastructure in scikit-learn is on model selection for out-of-sample prediction and therefore cross-validation on "test data".

This points out the distinction, there is still quite a lot of overlap also in the usage. statsmodels also does prediction, and additionally forecasting in a time series context.
But, when we want to do cross-validation for prediction in statsmodels it is currently still often easier to reuse the cross-validation setup of scikit-learn together with the estimation models of statsmodels.

Comment: Hmm, I'm trying to use an ARMA model from statsmodels.tsa, but the interface of predict is completely different there. Do you know how to feed it test data?

Comment: That's a different question, and you need to look at the documentation or examples. Prediction in time series models is pretty different because of the sequential time structure and prediction is forecasting of the values in the next time periods.

Comment: You're right that's another question, nevertheless  thanks for the explanation. I've read the documentation and got it to work somehow. But I still don't understand why the interface is different. Especially why it's not possible to provide feature vectors and get predictions (forecasts).

Comment: ARMA and SARIMAX allow for explanatory variables `exog` to be included in estimation and forecasting.

Comment: This question on Stackowerlow adresses the difference in interfaces: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41045752/using-statsmodel-estimations-with-scikit-learn-cross-validation-is-it-possible/

Answer (score 3):

In the OLS model you are using the training data to fit and predict.

With the LinearRegression model you are using training data to fit and test data to predict, therefore different results in R2 scores.

If you would take test data in OLS model, you should have same results and lower value

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered a similar issue where the OLS is giving different Rsquared and Adjusted Rsquared values compared to Sklearn LinearRegression model.

Reason for it: OLS does not consider, be default, the intercept coefficient and there builds the model without it and Sklearn considers it in building the model.

Solution: Add a column of 1's to the dataset and fit the model with OLS and you will get the almost same Rsquared and Adj. Rsquared values for both models.

Answer (score 1):

Let me make it crystal clear:
we know that multiple linear regression is represented as :

y = b0 + b1X1 + b2X2 + b3X3 +…..+ bnXn

but we can also, represent it as:
y = b0X0 + b1X1 + b2X2 + b3X3 +…..+ bnXn
where X0 = 1

We have to add one column with all the same values as 1 to represent b0X0.

Why we need to do that??
statsmodels Python library provides an OLS(ordinary least square) class for implementing Backward Elimination. Now one thing to note that OLS class **does not provide the intercept by default and it has to be created by the user himself.** That is why we created a column with all same values as 1 to represent b0X0.

Thats the reason why we get different R2 values in sklearn Regression model and Ols statsmodel.

Answer (score 0):

You can import statsmodels.formula.api if you would like the system to "take care" of the "add_constant" requirement on its own.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/349354)