# Wildly different $R^2$ between linear regression in statsmodels and sklearn

Tags: regression, python, scikit-learn, statsmodels

My question is related to:

[Difference between statsmodel OLS and scikit linear regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146804/difference-between-statsmodel-ols-and-scikit-linear-regression)

I essentially have the same problem, except my results are even more substantially different. Performing the following simple linear regressions, I get almost completely opposite results for the coefficient of determination:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn import linear_model

    x1 = [26.0, 31.0, 47.0, 51.0, 50.0, 49.0, 37.0, 33.0, 49.0, 54.0, 31.0, 49.0, 48.0, 49.0, 49.0, 47.0, 44.0, 48.0, 35.0, 43.0]
    y1 = [116.0, 94.0, 100.0, 102.0, 116.0, 116.0, 68.0, 118.0, 91.0, 104.0, 78.0, 116.0, 90.0, 109.0, 116.0, 118.0, 108.0, 119.0, 110.0, 102.0]

# Fit and summarize statsmodel OLS model
model_sm = sm.OLS(x1, y1)
result_sm = model_sm.fit()
print(result_sm.summary())


# Create sklearn linear regression object
ols_sk = linear_model.LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True)

# fit model
model_sk = ols_sk.fit(pd.DataFrame(x1), pd.DataFrame(y1))

# sklearn coefficient of determination
coefofdet = model_sk.score(pd.DataFrame(x1), pd.DataFrame(y1))

print('sklearn R^2: ' + str(coefofdet))
```

Statsmodels give me an $R^2$ of 0.962, while sklearn gives me an $R^2$ of 0.0584069073664.

What is causing such a drastic difference?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your `scikit-learn` model, you included an intercept using the `fit_intercept=True` method. This fit both your intercept and the slope.

In `statsmodels`, if you want to include an intercept, you need to run the command `x1 = stat.add_constant(x1)` in order to create a column of constants. Then running the `sm.OLS()` command would yield an R-squared value of around 0.056.

It's also important to note that when constructing a model in `statsmodels`, you want to put your `y1` first and `x1` second rather than `x1`, then `y1`. The arguments are reversed from `statsmodels` to `scikit-learn`.

Comment: And the source for the big changes in rsquared is that the definition changes depending on the presence or not of an intercept, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664471/why-would-r-squared-decrease-when-i-add-an-exogenous-variable-in-ols-using-pytho